# Upload http error products image

Tags: image-upload

i have tried every things to solve this issue.
So when i try to upload an product image with the size image over 100 kb there is this issue..
i already set into .htaccess SecFilterEngine Off,  post_max_size 16MB, upload_max_size 16MB there isn't protection password limitation i think and i have tried to set the secure url with http.

But it doesn't change.
Please help me, what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your apache error log.

Also ask your hosting provider if PHP is running in FastCGI mode and if there is **MaxRequestLen** limitation.

Comment: should i have to change php running fastcgi? in ssh could i see maxRequestLen limitation?

Comment: i have added in /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf  but the error remain                                           <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
   MaxRequestLen 2147483648
   FcgidMaxRequestLen 2147483648
</IfModule>

Comment: solve!! adding the MaxRequestLen 2147483648 FcgidMaxRequestLen 2147483648 it is gone

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a limitation at the web server level. You will need to contact your hosting provider to track down the exact cause of this and have them increase the limit for you if possible.